# $E[X | \mu-t \leq X \leq \mu+t] = \mu$ when $X$ is distributed symmetrically

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable with symmetric probability density function $f_X(x)$ and mean $\mu$.

Does $E[X | \mu-t \leq X \leq \mu+t] = \mu$ hold true for any $t$?

Edit:
let $A := [\mu -t \leq X \leq \mu+t]$ then

$E[X | X \in A] = \frac{\int_{\mu -t}^{\mu + t} x*f_X(x) dx}{\int_{\mu - t}^{\mu + t}f_X(x) dx}$ and

$E[X] = p(X \in A)*E[X | X \in A] + p(X \notin A)*E[X | X \notin A]$

$\Longrightarrow E[X | X \in A] = \frac{E[X]-p(X \notin A)*E[X | X \notin A]}{p(X \in A)} = \frac{\int_0^\infty x*f_X(x)dx*\frac{\int_0^{\mu-t}x*f_X(x)dx + \int_{\mu-t}^{\infty}x*f_X(x)dx}{\int_0^{\mu-t}f_X(x)dx + \int_{\mu-t}^{\infty}f_X(x)dx}}{\int_{\mu - t}^{\mu + t}f_X(x) dx} =  ?$

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Edited my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the substitution $u = 2\mu-x$ along with $f_X(2\mu-u) = f_X(u)$ in $$\int_{\mu-t}^{\mu+t} x f_X(x)\,dx$$
to yield
$$\int_{2\mu-(\mu-t)}^{2\mu-(\mu+t)} (2\mu-u)f_X(2\mu-u)\,(-du) = 2\mu\int_{\mu-t}^{\mu+t}f_X(u)\,du - \int_{\mu-t}^{\mu+t}uf_X(u)\,du.$$

Using $x$ as our variable we're integrating everywhere, this shows
$$\int_{\mu-t}^{\mu+t} xf_X(x)\,dx = 2{\color{red}\mu}\int_{\mu-t}^{\mu+t} f_X(x)\,dx - \int_{\mu-t}^{\mu+t} xf_X(x)\,dx.$$

Solve for the red $\color{red}\mu$.

---

**Note:** We must have $\int_{\mu-t}^{\mu+t} f_X(x)\,dx > 0$ for this to work.  Obviously this means $t > 0$ but this isn't sufficient for the integral to be positive (it depends $f_X$ as well)